# Appending list box to dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I choose any item from my dropdown the list box gets appended to dropdown with set of values but the problem is as the list box contains many values so it becomes larger and the dropdown goes down to the end of list box..
this is my html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">

    <title>D3</title>
    <style>
        body {
            color: #000;
        }
        .axis {
            font: 10px sans-serif;
        }

        .axis path,
        .axis line {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #000;
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }
        .bar {
            fill: steelblue;
        }

        .bar:hover {
            fill: brown;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="my_script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<body>
<div id="chart"></div>
<div align="center">
    From : <input type="date" name="field1" id="field1" /> To : <input type="date" name="field2" id="field2" /><br /><br />
    <input type="button" onclick="render(true)" value="Submit" />
</div>

 <script>
    function ShowHideListBox(e) {

        var IsOpen = $('#listbox').attr('IsOpen')
        if (IsOpen == "false") {
            ShowList(e.target)
        }
        else {
            HideList(e.target)
        }
    }

    function ShowList(elem) {
        $('#listbox').attr('IsOpen', 'true')
        $('#listbox').show()
    }

    function HideList(elem) {
        $('#listbox').attr('IsOpen', 'false')
        $('#listbox').hide()
    }

</script>


<script>
    var jsonURL = 'data.json';

    var myData = [];

    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 80,
        left: 40
    };
    var width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);
    var yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
    var hAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient('bottom').tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d"));
    var vAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient('left');
    var tooltip = d3.select('body').append('div')
            .style('position', 'absolute')
            .style('background', '#f4f4f4')
            .style('padding', '5 15px')
            .style('border', '1px #333 solid')
            .style('border-radius', '5px')
            .style('opacity', 'o');

    function getDates() {
        return [document.getElementById('field1').value, document.getElementById('field2').value];
    }

    function render(filterByDates) {

        d3.select('svg').remove();

        if (filterByDates) {
            var date1 = new Date(document.getElementById('field1').value);
            var date2 = new Date(document.getElementById('field2').value);

            myData = myData.filter(function(d) {
                return d.date >= date1 && d.date <= date2;
            });
        }

        xScale.domain(myData.map(function(d) {
            return d.date;
        }));

        yScale.domain([0, d3.max(myData, function(d) {
            return d.value;
        })]);

        var svg = d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        svg
                .append('g')
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(hAxis)
                .selectAll("text")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .attr("dx", "-.8em")
                .attr("dy", "-.55em")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");

        svg
                .append('g')
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(vAxis)

        svg
                .selectAll(".bar")
                .data(myData)
                .enter().append("rect")
                .attr("class", "bar")
                .style("fill", "steelblue")
                .attr("x", function(d) {
                    return xScale(d.date);
                })
                .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
                .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return yScale(d.value);
                })
                .attr("height", function(d) {
                    return height - yScale(d.value);
                })
                .on('mouseover', function(d) {
                    tooltip.transition()
                            .style('opacity', 1)

                    tooltip.html(d.value)
                            .style('left', (d3.event.pageX) + 'px')
                            .style('top', (d3.event.pagey) + 'px')
                    d3.select(this).style('opacity', 0.5)
                })
                .on('mouseout', function(d) {
                    tooltip.transition()
                            .style('opacity', 0)
                    d3.select(this).style('opacity', 1)
                });
    }

    d3.json(jsonURL, function(data) {
        myData = data;
        myData.forEach(function(d) {
            d.date = new Date(d.date);
            d.name = +d.name;
        });

        render(false);
    });
</script>


<label> List of Tables : </label><br>


    <form name="myform" id="myForm">
        <select id="dropdown1" onclick="return ShowHideListBox(event)"></select>


        <select id="listbox" multiple style="display:none; cursor:default;" isopen="false"></select>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

My js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "data.json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(obj) {
            var jsObject = obj;
            var usedNames = [];



            $('<option>', {
                text: 'Select your Option',
                value: '',
                selected: 'selected',
                disabled: 'disabled'
            }).appendTo('#dropdown1');


            $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
                if (usedNames.indexOf(value.name) == -1) {
                    $("#dropdown1").append("<option value=" + key + ">" + value.name + "</option>");
                    usedNames.push(value.name);
                }

                $('#dropdown1').change(function() {
                    $('#listbox').empty();

                    $('<option>', {
                        text: 'Select your List Option',
                        value: '',
                        selected: 'selected',
                        disabled: 'disabled'
                    }).appendTo('#listbox');

                    var selection = $('#dropdown1 :selected').text();
                 //   var selection = $('#dropdown1 :selected').text();
                    $.each(jsObject, function(index, value) {
                        if (value['name'] == selection) {
                            var optionHtml = '';
                            for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
                                var attr = 'attr' + ('000' + i).substr(-3);
                                optionHtml += '<option value="' + attr + '">' + value[attr] + '</option>';
                            }

                            $("#listbox").css("width","500px")

                            $("#listbox").css("height","300px")
                            $('#listbox').append(optionHtml); return false;
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding. Can you post a jsfiddle or clarify what you expect and what is happening?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: problem is as the list box becomes larger means the size of list box is large so the dropdown gets appended to the list box at the end... first before selecting anything from dropdown the dropdown is *up* but after selecting an item from dropdown as the list box comes the dopdown shifts its position down to the end of list box

Comment: anybodyy therereee....

Comment: It's tricky to understand without a working example, are you capable of providing a link?

Comment: Can i send u the image..i can't directly show the code..a screenshot of what i m getting

Comment: How about reproducing in a jsfiddle? Just a lot easier to physically see what you're referring to.